# ctypes callback function throws SIGSEGV

Tags: c, python-3.x, callback, segmentation-fault, shared-libraries

I got a c library, that needs some callbacks,
they are handled in a linked list.

the python callable are those:

```
def callback_exit():
    print("exiting.")
    sys.exit(0)
    # never reached
    return c_int(0)
def hw_print_int():
    print("foo")
    return c_int(0)
```

I add them to the list like this:

```
SFR_COMM=CFUNCTYPE(c_voidp)

class MyClass:
    def add_SFR_callback(self,operation_number,callback):
            all_callbacks=c_voidp.in_dll(self.memlib,"sfr_comms")
            my_callback=self.memlib.newSFRCommand(c_uint(operation_number),callback)
            new_all_callbacks=self.memlib.new_SFRCommandHolder(my_callback,all_callbacks)
            self.memlib.set_sfr_comms(new_all_callbacks)

my_class_object.add_SFR_callback(0xff,SFR_COMM(callback_exit))
my_class_object.add_SFR_callback(0xff,SFR_COMM(hw_print_int))
```

this works fine, until the callback is called, then I receive just a SIGSEGV.

***Important***: the SIGSEGV tells me, that it is an "Ungültiger Maschinenbefehl" (Translation: *invalid processor directive* or something like that)

So I just do not know how I can fix it.

This is the c code:

```
struct _SFRCommandHolder * sfr_comms;
#define DEBUG
unsigned int SpecialFunctionRegister_exec(unsigned int val)
{
    struct _SFRCommandHolder * curr=sfr_comms;
    unsigned int ret=-1;
    while (curr!=NULL)
    {
            #ifdef DEBUG
            printf("( %zd => %zd => %zd ) %u ?= %u",curr,curr->com,curr->com->funct,curr->com->val,val);
            #endif
            if(curr->com->val==val)
            {
                    #ifdef DEBUG
                    printf("\t\tTRUE\n");
                    #endif

                    ret=curr->com->funct(); // <= SIGSEGV here
                    #ifdef DEBUG
                    printf("callback done.\n");
                    #endif
            }
            #ifdef DEBUG
            else
            {
                    printf("\t\tFALSE\n");
            }
            #endif
            curr=curr->next;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I do not think, that `sys.exit` is a problem, as it worked a few commits before just fine.

***Edit***: 
calling `hw_print_int` works just fine, but `callback_exit` does not work.

btw: if I do not add `hw_print_int`, `callback_exit` works, too

output:

```
 ( 13185760 => 13136448 => 139994994819144 ) 3 ?= 255       FALSE
 ( 13038864 => 13034576 => 139994994819088 ) 255 ?= 255     TRUE
 Ungültiger Maschinenbefehl (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
```

Comment: Try initializing sfr_comms to NULL.

Comment: @cup that is not the problem. my memory handling is valid. (I tested it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that the python garbage collection removes
objects without (strong) reference to them.

**From  [https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#callback-functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#callback-functions__)**

> Note
>
> Make sure you keep references to CFUNCTYPE() objects as long as they are used from C code. ctypes doesn’t, and if you don’t, they may be garbage collected, crashing your program when a callback is made.
>
> Also, note that if the callback function is called in a thread created outside of Python’s control (e.g. by the foreign code that calls the callback), ctypes creates a new dummy Python thread on every invocation. This behavior is correct for most purposes, but it means that values stored with threading.local will not survive across different callbacks, even when those calls are made from the same C thread.

It seems like it is not enough to reference to them using the `struct _SFRCommandHolder *`.

So adding another reference is enough:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self,*args):
         # ...
         self.refs=[]
    def add_SFR_callback(self,operation_number,callback):
        all_callbacks=c_voidp.in_dll(self.memlib,"sfr_comms")
        my_callback=self.memlib.newSFRCommand(c_uint(operation_number),callback)
        new_all_callbacks=self.memlib.new_SFRCommandHolder(my_callback,all_callbacks)
        self.memlib.set_sfr_comms(new_all_callbacks)
        self.refs.append(callback)
```

Answer (score 1):

In here, you have pointers to `struct _SFRCommandHolder` but where does the data live? Where did you allocated a `struct _SFRCommandHolder`?

If the response is "nowhere", your code has undefined behaviour as sfr_comms may have **any** value (and especially non NULL value); this result in `curr->com` causing segmentation fault almost everytime.

Comment: both the  `struct _SFRCommandHolder` and the callback are valid ptrs. (see: I printed them) in `new_SFRCommandHolder`  I alloc the space for the `struct _SFRCommandHolder`. AND: if I call  the `hw_print_int` it works.

Comment: are you sure, the sys.exit() is available? If you remove this call, from the callback, does it still crash?

Comment: sys.exit does not change anything. bu could it be, that python removes my function object?

Comment: well maybe, see the answer of LittleByBlue

Comment: well, that's me!  ( I tested it) Thank you for your help. +1 for a asking the (in general) right question.